# Right way of comparing java.sql.Time in Java

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

Which is the right way to compare `Time` in Java?

I mean `java.sql.Time`.

Or is there a better way we can compare time in Joda Time?

Comment: it depends on the situation , if you have very frequent time related operation go for joda time , if you are comparing it less frequently you can use Time or even Calendar

Comment: Please give us more details of what you're trying to do. "The right way" depends on what your aim is. (And also, the names are Java and Joda Time, not JAVA and JODA.)

Comment: Since it's `java.sql.Time`, is it possible that the right solution to your problem would be to rely on the DBMS and do all the comparisons in SQL ? Perhaps more details about your use-case could help in finding the suitable way to go here...

Comment: @Jon, i'm using web service and in xml i just give say 09:00:00. When it binds it gets done as XMLGreorialCalendar. I have converted this into java.sql.time. Now I want to check with current time.

Comment: @Sripaul: Check *what* with the current time? Check whether the current local time is before or after 9am?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you can use Joda Time do so.  Convert all sql types to Joda equivalents at the persistence layer and then work with Joda objects in your business logic.  You won't regret it, believe me.

LocalTime is probably the object you want to use then you can use `compareTo()`, `isAfter()`, `isBefore()`.  Its also really easy to merge this into a full DateTime if necessary.